Where to output a bash script that tracks changes in a folder
My use case:

I have Terraform code that spins up a GCP VM.
Within the Terraform code, there is a startup script that creates a user and adds a password, and does several other bits, like changing the user permissions to one folder.
The goal is to have an automatic spin server for SFTP data exchange for several data providers.
Everything is working nicely, but the missing bit is when the files get uploaded, I want them to transfer to GCP Bucket automatically. This is needed for other pipeline runs related to Cloud Functions and Vertex AI.
I have a bash script that uses inotifywait and it is operational when I run it. However, the thing is that I want this script to run itself.

Script example:
#!/usr/bin/bash
dir1=/home/data/
while inotifywait -qqre "attrib,modify,close_write,move,move_self,create,delete,delete_self" "$dir1"; do
    gsutil cp -r "$dir1" gs://bucket_name
done

Now, in the startup script, I am trying to run this as part of a big startup script (adding only this part):
"#! /bin/bash\nsudo while inotifywait -qqre \"attrib,modify,close_write,move,move_self,create,delete,delete_self\" \"/home/$folder_name/\"; do gsutil cp -r \"/home/$folder_name/\" gs://bucket_name done\ncat <<EOF > /var/www/html/index.html\n <html><body><p>Linux startup script added directly.</p></body></html>\n EOF"

Can I open the process as such or should I add this and write to a file? Should it be in /etc/profile so that it is always executed when a file is uploaded or do I have a cron setup to run every hour or so?
